# Why does the tag appear to be tightly coupled to hostname of the registry?

Tags: docker

I've been reading lot of tutorials on how to setup and use my own private docker registry.

One thing which stumped me is the fact that the tag I'm tagging the image with, appears to be tightly coupled to the hostname of the registry.

```
docker tag <imageid> registry.mycompany.com:5000/myrepo:tag
docker push registry.mycompany.com:5000/myrepo:tag
```

This seems really counter-intuitive. What happens if the registry has to move to a different hostname? Or if I'm using different hostnames whether or not I'm accessing the server internally/externally?

What seems more intuitive to me would be to specify the registry when pushing/pulling:

```
docker tag <imageid> myrepo:tag
docker push myrepo:tag --registry=registry.mycompany.com
docker pull myrepo:tag --registry=registry.mycompnay.com
```

What is the rationale for this? What key bit of information am I missing?

Comment: IMO that is not a good design. Host name should be decoupled with tag. Host should be a separte arg, default to docker.io when missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL/registry name is essentially the "namespace" for the image. If you don't specify a registry, the image is assumed to belong to the Docker Hub. In effect, this means that Docker Inc controls the global namespace.

If it wasn't done this way, you could have two completely different "pushed" images on separate hosts with the same name, which is something Docker want to avoid.

The moving of the registry server is a valid concern, so I would suggest you try to use a domain name rather than IP for your registry.

Answer (score 0):

> the tag I'm tagging the image with, appears to be tightly coupled to the hostname of the registry.

Not exactly: the registry is used in the url of the registry server used for pushing/pulling the image.

Even if you change of server, the image name you would use to push/pull would still be the same, only the url changes (as explained in [`library/registry`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/registry/) and [`docker/docker-registry`](https://github.com/docker/docker-registry)).

Comment: I don't follow - the URL *is* part of the name. If it's changed/removed you are (probably) referring to a different image.

Comment: @AdrianMouat that part of the name is for `docker push` to know what server it needs to contact. The second part should not change (although `:latest` is always a bit dangerous and might not refer to the same image from one server to another). If your registry server is stored in an environment variable, you can easily reuse the same expression on another server `${registryname}/myrepo:tag`.

Comment: `docker tag ubuntu ${registryname}/ubuntu` doesn't work. The docker client is not allowing this kind of naming

Comment: @shayy I meant that as an environment variable: the shell should substitue `${registryname}` with `registry.mycompany.com:5000`